# Paritition matrix into smaller matrices based on multiple values

Tags: python, matrix

So I have this giant matrix (~1.5 million rows x 7 columns) and am trying to figure out an efficient way to split it up. For simplicity of what I'm trying to do, I'll work with this much smaller matrix as an example for what I'm trying to do. The 7 columns consist of (in this order): item number, an x and y coordinate, 1st label (non-numeric), data #1, data #2, and 2nd label (non-numeric). So using pandas, I've imported from an excel sheet my matrix called A that looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is partition this based on both labels (i.e. so I have one matrix that is all the 13G + Aa together, another matrix that is 14G + Aa, and another one that is 14G + Ab together -- this would have me wind up with 3 separate 2x7 matrices). The reason for this is because I need to run a bunch of statistics on the dataset of numbers of the "Marker" column for each individual matrix (e.g. in this example, break the 6 "marker" numbers into three sets of 2 "marker" numbers, and then run statistics on each set of two numbers). Since there are going to be hundreds of these smaller matrices on the real data set I have, I was trying to figure out some way to make the smaller matrices be labeled something like M1, M2, ..., M500 (or whatever number it ends up being) so that way later, I can use some loops to apply statistics to each individual matrix all at once without having to write it 500+ times.

What I've done so far is to use pandas to import my data set into python as a matrix with the command:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\cancerdata.csv")
A = df.as_matrix() #Convert excel sheet to matrix
A = np.delete(A, (0),axis=0) #Delete header row
```

Unfortunately, I haven't come across many resources for how to do what I want, which is why I wanted to ask here to see if anyone knows how to split up a matrix into smaller matrices based on multiple labels.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has many implications, so instead of giving you a straight answer I'll try to give you some pointers on how to tackle this problem.

First off, don't transform your DataFrame into a Matrix. DataFrames are well-optimised for slicing and indexing operations (a Pandas Series object is in reality a fancy Numpy array anyway), so you only lose functionality by converting it to a Matrix.

You could probably convert your label columns into a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html). This way, you'll be able to access slices of your original DataFrame using `df.loc`, with a syntax similar to `df.loc[label1].loc[label2]`.

A MultiIndex may sound confusing at first, but it really isn't. Try executing this code block and see for yourself how the resulting DataFrame looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\path\cancerdata.csv")
labels01 = df["Label 1"].unique()
labels02 = df["Label 2"].unique()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([labels01, labels02])
df.set_index(index, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Here, we extracted all unique values in the columns "Label 1" and "Label 2", and created an MultiIndex based on all possible combinations of Label 1 vs. Label 2. In the `df.set_index` line, we extracted those columns from the DataFrame - now they act as indices for your other columns. For example, in order to access the DataFrame slice from your original DataFrame whose Label 1 = 13G and Label 2 = Aa, you can simply write:

```
sliced_df = df.loc["13G"].loc["Aa"]
```

And perform whatever calculations/statistics you need with it.

Lastly, instead of saving each sliced DataFrame into a list or dictionary, and then iterating over them to perform the calculations, consider rearranging your code so that, as soon as you create your sliced DataFrame, you peform the calculations, save them to a output/results file/DataFrame, and move on to the next slicing operation. Something like:

```
for L1 in labels01:
    for L2 in labels02:
        sliced_df = df.loc[L1].loc[L2]
        results = perform_calculations(sub_df)
        save_results(results)
```

This will both improve memory consumption and performance, which may be important considering your large dataset.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot for all this good information. I will play around with it and see if I can get it to do what I want. I tried executing the block of code you wrote out (in the first box) but it gives me this error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1843513 elements, new values have 3771 elements". The full data set has 1843513 rows which is where that number comes from. The second number I presume comes from the product of len(labels01)=419 and len(labels02)=9. I printed labels01 and labels02, and both those look correct thankfully, so not sure what is causing this error

Comment: Sounds like resetting the MultiIndex did not work as I expected. Try explicitly indicating the columns to use as indices when loading the dataframe, by adding the keyword argument `index_col=["Label 1", "Label 2"]` to the `pd.read_csv` call, and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Hopefully I understood the instructions correctly. So I did this in the code: df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path\cancerdata.csv", index_col=["TMA_Core_Position", "Array"]) -- TMA_Core_Position and Array are what are Label 1 and Label 2 in the giant excel sheet. This is giving me a KeyError: 'TMA_Core_Position'. If I misunderstood, please let me know!

Comment: Your code looks correct, are you sure that those names match the columns in cancerdata.csv? Is the file properly formatted, is there any misspelling (check uppercase/lowercase) and are the columns properly loaded as you expect them to, when you load the dataframe without the index_col argument?

Comment: I'm  pretty because I copied and pasted from the excel sheet (https://ibb.co/sRM086c). This is what python shows me when I go print(df) without the index_col: https://ibb.co/120X4G5 (Sorry for posting it as images -- couldn't think of a better way to do so in the comments!)